# Octopack artifacts includes source codes

Tags: c#, teamcity, octopus-deploy, octopack

I am having the following issue.

I am using a teamcity  build server with octopack, My build artifacts nouget package contains all of the source codes of our project.

I would not like them to be visible.

How should I look at this stuff?

Is this even a project setting or a setting for octopack?
I have tried setting the build action to none on c# files in visual studio and this has not had any effect.

I have also tried to use `<file src=".\Views\**\*.*" exclude=".\Views\." target="Views" />`
in my nuspec file.
This has made the build unsuccesfull with the error

> C:\BuildAgent\work\ab676e64aeb1c979\packages\OctoPack.1.0.109\targets\OctoPack.targets(122, 5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\BuildAgent\work\ab676e64aeb1c979********.****.****...nuget\NuGet.exe" pack "C:\BuildAgent\work\ab676e64aeb1c979********.****.************.****.nuspec" -OutputDirectory "bin"  -basePath "C:\BuildAgent\work\ab676e64aeb1c979********.****.****" -Version "1.1.0.6984" -NoPackageAnalysis" exited with code 1.

How do I go about this problem?

Comment: Have you looked into [nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec). `NuGet.exe` would use your `.nuspec` to create the package.

Comment: You are correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use nuspec file for packege your artifact with octopact please try this script .

exclude="obj***.*;obj\octopacking***.*;obj\octopacked***.*;obj\Release\Package***.*;***.pdb;***.ps1;***.dll.config;***.loadtest;_DeveloperNotes;_PublishedWebsites"

You can refactor it with your needs.